# Angular $location doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I created a plunkr for this code [and it can be viewed here:](http://plnkr.co/edit/wJ4LjcK6HmOPaLMqHbR9?p=catalogue)

The problem is very simple. I am trying to create a master/details scenario. So there are two templates: listings and details. In the listing controller there is a methods redirects to the detials route. This method works well as i verified it with the debugger (via breaking point).

```
 $scope.goToDetails = function(propItem) {
  //$rootScope.currentProperty = propItem;
  $location.path('/details/');

}
```

The 'details' path (see blow) calls the 'detailsController', which is currently (for testing purposes) defined as:

```
 var detailsController = function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $rootScope) {
    var dosomething = "do";
 };
```

I verified with the debugger that the execution indeed reaches the "dosomething" command and that the route changes in the browser to "details". However, and HERE is the problem, when I continue with the debugger, angular changes the route back to the default route. I went over the definitions but nothing that i did seems wrong.Any ideas?

Here is how I defined the routes:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/main/', routes.main)
  .when('/details/', routes.details)
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/main'
  });
});

var routes = {
  main: {
  templateUrl: 'PropertiesResults.html',
  controller: 'listingController'
},
details: {
  templateUrl: 'property-detail.html',
  controller: 'detailsController'
 },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="goToDetails(property)" ...
```

With:

```
<a href="" ng-click="goToDetails(property)" ...
```

Or it will go to your `otherwise` route.

Comment: Thanks :) that works. Funny that is the last place i thought of looking.

Comment: No problem. I know the feeling :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your link to be

```
<a href="#/details">Read More</a>
```

A few things to consider:

- Links should work just like in a regular html page
- If you want to execute code on a new page, look into putting that code on the route, or in a controller in the new view.
- If you want to conditionally enable or disable the link, think about disabling the link with something like `<a ng-disabled="expression"...` this might not work out of the box but you could add a custom directive.
- If you still need to run that code in a controller method, consider using a `<button type="button" class="link"...` and style it to look like a link, e.g. `display: inline; border: 0; background: transparent;`"

Happy coding